# C# set value of private variable

Tags: c#, mocking

this is the private value I want to set

```
 private PhaseList stages;
```

this is my test

```
    MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
        mocks.Stub<UserAction>();
        Game g = new Game(players, cardList);
        Type stage = typeof(PhaseList);
        FieldInfo stinfo = stage.GetField("stages",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        PhaseList p = new PhaseList();
        p.add(new DiscardPhase(players[0]));
        p.add(new DiscardPhase(players[0]));
        stinfo.SetValue(g, p);
        g.processUserInput(0, mocks.Stub<UserAction>());
```

I get this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It points to this line:

```
stinfo.SetValue(g, p);
```

I dont understand why stinfo=null;

Can anyone help me?

Comment: "this is the private value I want to set" - private variable of *what* class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to get the type of the `PhaseList` class, and then get a private field inside it named `stages`. It doesn't have a field named "stages", I'm assuming, so you get `null`.

What you *do* have is a field named "stages" in some *other* class that's potentially an instance of the `PhaseList` class.

```
Type stage = typeof(Whatever_Class_Has_The_Stages_Field_In_It);

FieldInfo stinfo = stage.GetField("stages", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```